# how to install php7 (zts) + pthreads on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, pthreads

I need an assistance for a full installation of PHP7 (ZTS) + Pthreads. I have tried the following installation but couldn't get it working.

```
sudo -i

apt-get update

apt-get install -y git bison autoconf build-essential pkg-config gitcore libltdl-dev libbz2-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libssl-dev libicu-dev libpspell-dev libenchant-dev libmcrypt-dev libpng-dev libjpeg8-dev libfreetype6-dev libmysqlclient-dev libreadline-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev

mkdir /etc/php7

mkdir /etc/php7/cli

cd /usr/local/src

git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git --depth=1

cd php-src/ext

git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads -b master pthreads

cd ..

./buildconf --force

php_configure_args="--prefix=/etc/php7 --with-config-file-path=/etc/php7/cli --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php7/cli/conf.d --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-zip --with-mcrypt --with-openssl --with-curl --enable-ftp --with-mysqli --enable-sockets --enable-pcntl --with-pspell --with-enchant --with-gettext --with-gd --enable-exif --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-freetype-dir --with-xsl --enable-bcmath --enable-mbstring --enable-calendar --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-debug --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --enable-cli --enable-pthreads=shared --with-tsrm-pthreads"


./configure $php_configure_args 

make && make install

cd /usr/local/src/php-src/ext/intl*

chmod a+x /etc/php7/bin/php-config

chmod a+x /etc/php7/bin/phpize

/etc/php7/bin/phpize

./configure --enable-intl --with-icu-dir=/usr  --prefix='/etc/php7' --with-libdir='/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --with-php-config='/etc/php7/bin/php-config'

make && make install

cp /usr/local/src/php-src/php.ini-production /etc/php7/cli/php.ini

ln --symbolic /etc/php7/bin/php /usr/bin/php

ln --symbolic /etc/php7/sbin/php-fpm /usr/sbin/php7-fpm

echo 'zend_extension=opcache.so' >> /etc/php7/cli/php.ini

echo 'extension=pthreads.so' >> /etc/php7/cli/php-cli.ini

echo "extension=intl.so" >> /etc/php7/cli/php.ini
```

FPM Configuration. 1) /etc/init.d/php7-fpm

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          php-fpm php7-fpm
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts php7-fpm
# Description:       Starts The PHP FastCGI Process Manager Daemon
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Ondrej Sury <ondrej@debian.org>
# Adapted to php7-fpm by @bjornjohansen

PATH=/usr/sbin
DESC="PHP7 FastCGI Process Manager"
NAME=php7-fpm
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="--daemonize --fpm-config /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf"
PIDFILE=/var/run/php7-fpm.pid
TIMEOUT=30
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Don't run if we are running upstart
if init_is_upstart; then
    exit 1
fi

#
# Function to check the correctness of the config file
#
do_check()
{
    /usr/local/lib/php7-fpm-checkconf || return 1
    return 0
}

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running  
    #   2 if daemon could not be started  
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec          $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
            || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
            $DAEMON_ARGS 2>/dev/null \
            || return 2
    # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
    # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
    # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
        # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=QUIT/$TIMEOUT/TERM/5/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
    # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
    # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other    code
    # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
    # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
    # sleep for some time.
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --   retry=0/30/TERM/5/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
    #
    # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
    # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
    # then implement that here.
    #
    start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR2 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_check $VERBOSE
    case "$?" in
        0)
            do_start
            case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
            esac
            ;;
        1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
            0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
            2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
status)
    status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
check)
    do_check yes
    ;;
reload|force-reload)
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_reload
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
reopen-logs)
    log_daemon_msg "Reopening $DESC logs" $NAME
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR1 --oknodo --quiet \
        --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
    then
        log_end_msg 0
    else
        log_end_msg 1
    fi
    ;;
restart)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
            do_start
            case "$?" in
                    0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
                    1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
                    *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
            esac
            ;;
      *)
            # Failed to stop
            log_end_msg 1
            ;;
    esac
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|reload|force-  reload}" >&2
    exit 1
;;
esac
```

chmod a+x /etc/init.d/php7-fpm

2) /etc/init/php7-fpm.conf

```
# php7-fpm - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
# Original script by Ondřej Surý. Adapted to php7-fpm by @bjornjohansen

description "The PHP FastCGI Process Manager"
author "Ondřej Surý <ondrej@debian.org>"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

# Precise upstart does not support reload signal, and thus rejects the
# job. We'd rather start the daemon, instead of forcing users to
# reboot https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1272788
#
# reload signal USR2


pre-start exec /usr/local/lib/php7-fpm-checkconf

respawn
exec /usr/sbin/php7-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf
```

3) /usr/local/lib/php7-fpm-checkconf

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
errors=$(/usr/sbin/php7-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf -t 2>&1 | grep "\[ERROR\]" || $
if [ -n "$errors" ]; then
    echo "Please fix your configuration file..."
    echo $errors
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

chmod a+x /usr/local/lib/php7-fpm-checkconf

```
cp /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf.default /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf

cp /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.default /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

update-rc.d -f php7-fpm defaults
```

When I run the following I got the error message "Job failed to start"

```
service php7-fpm start
```

I will be glad if someone can correct my mistake or provide a full installation of PHP7 (ZTS) + Pthreads enabled.

Comment: What are those semicolons doing up there when you are already (over)using line breaks? Simply do `sudo apt-get`...etc. and join the backslashed lines together, just leave one space between each package name.

Comment: thanks for pointing them out; i've removed them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update and Install Dependencies

```
apt-get update

apt-get install -y bison autoconf build-essential pkg-config git-core libltdl-dev libbz2-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libssl-dev libicu-dev libpspell-dev libenchant-dev libmcrypt-dev libpng-dev libjpeg8-dev libfreetype6-dev libmysqlclient-dev libreadline-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Remove any existing php7 and recreate php7 and other subdirectories

```
rm -rf /etc/php7

mkdir -p /etc/php7
mkdir -p /etc/php7/cli
mkdir -p /etc/php7/etc
```

Remove any php-src folder in your current working directory and reinstall from git branch

```
rm -rf php-src

git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git --depth=1
```

Change directory to ext to download pthreads from git

```
cd php-src/ext

git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads -b master pthreads
```

Go back to php-src as your current working directory

```
cd ..
```

Build the php-src

```
./buildconf --force
```

Set configure options, enable zts, fpm, and other extensions applicable to your own case

```
CONFIGURE_STRING="--prefix=/etc/php7 --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-zip --disable-cgi \
   --enable-soap --enable-intl --with-mcrypt --with-openssl --with-readline --with-curl \
   --enable-ftp --enable-mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
   --enable-sockets --enable-pcntl --with-pspell --with-enchant --with-gettext \
   --with-gd --enable-exif --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-freetype-dir --with-xsl \
   --enable-bcmath --enable-mbstring --enable-calendar --enable-simplexml --enable-json \
   --enable-hash --enable-session --enable-xml --enable-wddx --enable-opcache \
   --with-pcre-regex --with-config-file-path=/etc/php7/cli \
   --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php7/etc --enable-cli --enable-maintainer-zts \
   --with-tsrm-pthreads --enable-debug --enable-fpm \
   --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data"
```

Run configure script and install

```
./configure $CONFIGURE_STRING

make && make install
```

Make the following helper programs executable

```
chmod o+x /etc/php7/bin/phpize

chmod o+x /etc/php7/bin/php-config
```

Now change directory to pthreads and run phpize

```
cd ext/pthreads*

/etc/php7/bin/phpize
```

Set configuration options for pthreads, but make sure enable-pthreads=shared which is the main aspect of the configuration

```
./configure --prefix='/etc/php7' --with-libdir='/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' \ 
    --enable-pthreads=shared --with-php-config='/etc/php7/bin/php-config'

make && make install
```

FPM Installation involves copying configuration files to appropriate positions and making changes where necessary.

```
#back to current working directory php-src

cd ../../

#php.ini to be used by fpm-fcgi

cp -r php.ini-production /etc/php7/cli/php.ini

sed -i 's/;date.timezone =.*/date.timezone = Africa\/Lagos/' /etc/php7/cli/php.ini

cp /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf.default /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf

cp /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.default /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

cp sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm /etc/init.d/php7-fpm

sed -i 's/Provides:          php-fpm/Provides:          php7-fpm/' /etc/init.d/php7-fpm

sed -i 's#^php_fpm_BIN=.*#php_fpm_BIN=/usr/sbin/php7-fpm#' /etc/init.d/php7-fpm

sed -i 's#^php_fpm_CONF=.*#php_fpm_CONF=/etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf#' /etc/init.d/php7-fpm

sed -i 's#^php_fpm_PID=.*#php_fpm_PID=/var/run/php7-fpm.pid#' /etc/init.d/php7-fpm
```

Add pthreads.so to php-cli.ini, this will used by command line interface (CLI)

```
cp php.ini-production /etc/php7/cli/php-cli.ini

echo "extension=pthreads.so" > /etc/php7/cli/php-cli.ini
```

Add other extensions and link binaries

```
echo "zend_extension=opcache.so" >> /etc/php7/cli/php.ini

ln --symbolic /etc/php7/bin/php /usr/bin/php

ln --symbolic /etc/php7/sbin/php-fpm /usr/sbin/php7-fpm

chmod +x /etc/init.d/php7-fpm

update-rc.d php7-fpm defaults

service php7-fpm start
```

Make sure the following are as they are in /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf

```
pid = /var/run/php7-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php7-fpm.log
include=/etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

Make sure the following are as they are in /etc/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php7-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php7
```

Make sure the following are as they are in /etc/php7/cli/php.ini

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
```

To use with Nginx do the following in your nginx/sites-available/default

```
upstream php7-fpm {
    server unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php7-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

service nginx restart
```

To use pthreads, remember it works via command line interface. Assuming thread.php is your parallel programming code, you can't run it in sapi/fpm mode by doing localhost/path/to/thread.php with your browser

```
<?php
//thread.php
    class Part extends Threaded{ public function run(){} }
    $parts = new Part();

    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) $parts[] = $i;
?>
```

Instead you create a file to execute your code thread.php via command line methods like "system"

```
<?php
    system("php /path/to/thread.php");
?>
```

Comment: I need to use it in fpm mode. There are a solution with your guide??

Comment: Thank you so much, helped me a lot!

Comment: @cleaversdev no, there's no any way to use it in fpm. Threading in php only in cli mode.

As said Joe:
pthreads v3 is restricted to operating in CLI only: I have spent many years trying to explain that threads in a web server just don't make sense, after 1,111 commits to pthreads I have realised that, my advice is going unheeded.
So I'm promoting the advice to hard and fast fact: you can't use pthreads safely and sensibly anywhere but CLI.

[More info](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads)

Comment: Can anybody confirm that this answer is still valid on June 2017?

Answer (score 4):

This is a co-install with PHP 5.6 & PHP 7.0 (zts or not)

We kick out legacy PHP5 packages and install co-installable PHP 5.6 & PHP 7.0 packages

```
apt-get autoremove php5 php5-common
```

apache2 should complain at the moment but it's ok, we'll fix it
Add custom repo ( php packages debian maintainer repo )

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Edit the source list file, most likely `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-trusty.list`, and uncomment the source line
Then :

```
apt-get update
```

Install non-zts version from the repo (we'll replace them later)

```
apt-get install php5.6 php5.6-fpm php7.0 php7.0-fpm
```

Now let's compile !

```
apt-get build-dep php7.0
apt-get source php7.0
cd php7.0-*
nano debian/rules
```

Edit the compilation configure step to add the --enable-maintainer-zts option.
Search for "dh_install" and remove the "--fail-missing" option.

Now do :

```
./debian/rules binary
```

Compilation will go, and packaging will fail. But now we have the package structure

Look at the error message, it will complain of missing default config file.
Copy these file from your php non-zts install into the package structure, at the location you see in the error message.
Now recast :

```
./debian/rules binary
```

It should succeed. Now you can install all but the snmp package, which I don't know why, but f*ck everything up.

```
rm php7.0-snmp*.deb
dpkg -i php7.0*.deb
```

You can try with :

```
php7.0 -r 'echo "Hello World";'
```

It should works :D
Do it again with the 5.6 version if you want it ZTS too.

Now let's plug it into apache.

```
a2dismod mpm_prefork
a2enmod mpm_event
a2enmod actions fastcgi proxy proxy_fcgi
a2dismod php5.6
a2dismod php7.0
```

Now we create a bridge between the request received by apache2 and the fpm'cgi by creating the conf file :

`/etc/apache2/conf-available/php5.6-cgi.conf`

```
AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
Action php5-fcgi /php5.6
Alias /php5.6 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.6

FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.6 -appConnTimeout 10 -idle-timeout 9000 -socket 127.0.0.1:7056 -pass-header Authorization
```

Same for PHP 7 :

`/etc/apache2/conf-available/php7.0-cgi.conf`

```
AddHandler php7-fcgi .php
Action php7-fcgi /php7.0
Alias /php7.0 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.0

FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.0 -appConnTimeout 10 -idle-timeout 9000 -socket 127.0.0.1:7070 -pass-header Authorization
```

Comment out the content of the default fastcgi's bridge :

`/etc/apache2/mods-available/fastcgi.conf`

Tell FPM where you're going to talk to him :

In `/etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` find the listen parameter (page 2) and set it to

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:7056
```

And again for PHP 7.0

`/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:7070
```

Update your vhost by telling them what FPM to use (inside vhost, outside the ), here php 7.0 :

```
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
            SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:7070
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml|ps)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
```

By now it works, but we're going to add some extra stuff, php-mysql & some more :

```
apt-get install php{5.6,7.0}-{mysql,mcrypt} php-xdebug
phpenmod -v ALL -s ALL mysqli pdo_mysql readline xdebug
```

Update xdebug config (below is mine) :

`/etc/php/mods-available/xdebug.ini`

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.overload_var_dump = 0
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
```

Then

```
systemctl enable php{5.6,7.0}-fpm
```

Ultimately we restart everything

```
systemctl restart apache2
systemctl restart php{5.6,7.0}-fpm
```

## And you should be done :D

Comment: Hi JesusTheHun, I've been having errors on this line of the configuration: ./debian/rules binary. Twas really frustrating so I made another attempt https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/555, but in this attempt all pthread classes work except Stackable. Can you take a look to this installation in case you may have a contribution.

Comment: Github is not a place to ask for help. Delete your issue please.
What are the errors you get when you execute ./debian/rules binary ?

Comment: i've closed the issue, it's not even an error, little did i know that Stackable is not defined in the current Pthreads. so instead of Stackable one can use StackableArray that extends class Threaded. Hence I assume my new installation will serve my need. meanwhile let me retry your solution on a new virtualbox instance to have it as alternative solution just in case.

Comment: You can you Threaded directly if you just need to transport data from one context to another, use Volatile if you plan to modify them.

Comment: @JesusTheHun what parts of your solution should I skip in order to install only php7?