# How to install pthreads on php7 and apache2 to use it in websites

Tags: php, apache, pthreads

I want to use threads in php7 on my website, not in CLI. Most tutorials are explaining how to use them on php-cli. I want it on apache websites. First I tried to recompile php7 with zts enabled from [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969325/how-to-install-php7-zts-pthreads-on-ubuntu-14-04). Not only it didn't work in browsers but also I destroyed my server setup (first mysqli was wrong version, now nothing works).

This attempt is made on virtualbox.
Here are the steps I made:

```
mkdir phpinstall && cd phpinstall

wget php.net/distributions/php-7.1.0.tar.gz
wget https://pecl.php.net/get/

tar zxvf php-7.1.0.tar.gz 
tar zxvf pthreads-3.1.6.tgz

rm pthreads-3.1.6.tgz
rm php-7.1.0.tar.gz

cp pthreads-3.1.6 /php-7.1.0/ext/pthreads

sudo apt-get install make build-essential -y
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev -y


./buildconf --force

#should show pthreads 
./configure --help | grep pthreads

rm -rf aclocal.m4
rm -rf autom4te.cache/
./buildconf --force

#./configure --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads --enable-debug 
#but i used below, thinking that phtreads should be in php7 already build in:
./configure --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-debug 

sudo make && sudo make install

#now installed apache via apt-get

sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php
echo "extension=pthreads.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
echo "extension=pthreads.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
service apache2 restart
```

I also installed ubuntu-desktop because I couldn't get IP to browse server from host.

Php works in browser but it has no pthreads enabled. That's probably because I skipped `--enable-pthreads`. I did that because I had errors and php couldn't install. 
When I want to install pthreads with pecl I am getting this error:

```
Makefile:196: recipe for target 'php_pthreads.so' failed
make: *** [php_pthreads.so] Error 1
```

In this output I saw 'zts enabled' so at least that have worked. I got whole file with output of `pecl install pthreads` but I'm skipping it for now not to spam here. If you want it write in comments. The same error was appearing when I was making php7 with --enable-pthreads.
No errors in apache error log. Php7 should have pthreads build in so why they are not working?

What I am doing wrong?
Ubuntu 16.10, apache2, php7.1.0, pthreads 3.6.* (latest)

**EDIT:**
I tried pthreads v3.0.5 and 2.0.10 and it still doesn't install. Same error as before.

**EDIT2:**
For those looking for answer: it is rather impossible to install pthreads to work with apache.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you think to need phtreads? Most of us can live fine with a single thread and our lives are easier, too.

Comment: One reason is to learn threads in php and second is that I'd like to perform two tasks at once. @PeeHaa could give link to other post you said I had duplicated? maybe there's solution there.

Comment: The link is added to the top of your question where the author of the extension explains "no can do".

Comment: Well, on pecl site in changelog i found that since v3.0.6 they allow only cli. In  krakjoe's readme I found v3 wont work w apache. So I tried to install first v3.0.5 then v2.0.10 and still got the same error. It just doesn't want to install for regardless if  for apache or cli

Comment: Missing the point. You are...